# Spanish accents in Sphinx searches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I've just included thinking-sphinx on Ruby-on-rails and I wanted to know how and where I must config the chartset_table so if I search some word with an accent, it returns results as if the word didn't have the accent.

**EDIT:**

This is my Sphinx.yml config file. Please let me know if there's something wrong with it:

```
development:
  bin_path: D:\xxxxx\xxxxx\sphinx\bin
  searchd_binary_name: searchd
  indexer_binary_name: indexer
  charset_type: utf-8
  allow_star: true
  charset_table: "0..9, a..z, _, A..Z->a..z, U+00C0->a, U+00C1->a, U+00C2->a, U+00C3->a, U+00C4->a, U+00C5->a, U+00C7->c, U+00C8->e,        U+00C9->e, U+00CA->e, U+00CB->e, U+00CC->i, U+00CD->i, U+00CE->i,        U+00CF->i, U+00D1->n, U+00D2->o, U+00D3->o, U+00D4->o, U+00D5->o,        U+00D6->o, U+00D9->u, U+00DA->u, U+00DB->u, U+00DC->u, U+00DD->y,        U+00E0->a, U+00E1->a, U+00E2->a, U+00E3->a, U+00E4->a, U+00E5->a,        U+00E7->c, U+00E8->e, U+00E9->e, U+00EA->e, U+00EB->e, U+00EC->i,        U+00ED->i, U+00EE->i, U+00EF->i, U+00F1->n, U+00F2->o, U+00F3->o,        U+00F4->o, U+00F5->o, U+00F6->o, U+00F9->u, U+00FA->u, U+00FB->u,        U+00FC->u, U+00FD->y, U+00FF->y, U+0100->a, U+0101->a, U+0102->a,        U+0103->a, U+0104->a, U+0105->a, U+0106->c, U+0107->c, U+0108->c,        U+0109->c, U+010A->c, U+010B->c, U+010C->c, U+010D->c, U+010E->d,        U+010F->d, U+0112->e, U+0113->e, U+0114->e, U+0115->e, U+0116->e,        U+0117->e, U+0118->e, U+0119->e, U+011A->e, U+011B->e, U+011C->g,        U+011D->g, U+011E->g, U+011F->g, U+0120->g, U+0121->g, U+0122->g,        U+0123->g, U+0124->h, U+0125->h, U+0128->i, U+0129->i, U+012A->i,        U+012B->i, U+012C->i, U+012D->i, U+012E->i, U+012F->i, U+0130->i,        U+0134->j, U+0135->j, U+0136->k, U+0137->k, U+0139->l, U+013A->l,        U+013B->l, U+013C->l, U+013D->l, U+013E->l, U+0142->l, U+0143->n,        U+0144->n, U+0145->n, U+0146->n, U+0147->n, U+0148->n, U+014C->o,        U+014D->o, U+014E->o, U+014F->o, U+0150->o, U+0151->o, U+0154->r,        U+0155->r, U+0156->r, U+0157->r, U+0158->r, U+0159->r, U+015A->s,        U+015B->s, U+015C->s, U+015D->s, U+015E->s, U+015F->s, U+0160->s,        U+0161->s, U+0162->t, U+0163->t, U+0164->t, U+0165->t, U+0168->u,        U+0169->u, U+016A->u, U+016B->u, U+016C->u, U+016D->u, U+016E->u,        U+016F->u, U+0170->u, U+0171->u, U+0172->u, U+0173->u, U+0174->w,        U+0175->w, U+0176->y, U+0177->y, U+0178->y, U+0179->z, U+017A->z,        U+017B->z, U+017C->z, U+017D->z, U+017E->z, U+01A0->o, U+01A1->o,        U+01AF->u, U+01B0->u, U+01CD->a, U+01CE->a, U+01CF->i, U+01D0->i,        U+01D1->o, U+01D2->o, U+01D3->u, U+01D4->u, U+01D5->u, U+01D6->u,        U+01D7->u, U+01D8->u, U+01D9->u, U+01DA->u, U+01DB->u, U+01DC->u,        U+01DE->a, U+01DF->a, U+01E0->a, U+01E1->a, U+01E6->g, U+01E7->g,        U+01E8->k, U+01E9->k, U+01EA->o, U+01EB->o, U+01EC->o, U+01ED->o,        U+01F0->j, U+01F4->g, U+01F5->g, U+01F8->n, U+01F9->n, U+01FA->a,        U+01FB->a, U+0200->a, U+0201->a, U+0202->a, U+0203->a, U+0204->e,        U+0205->e, U+0206->e, U+0207->e, U+0208->i, U+0209->i, U+020A->i,        U+020B->i, U+020C->o, U+020D->o, U+020E->o, U+020F->o, U+0210->r,        U+0211->r, U+0212->r, U+0213->r, U+0214->u, U+0215->u, U+0216->u,        U+0217->u, U+0218->s, U+0219->s, U+021A->t, U+021B->t, U+021E->h,        U+021F->h, U+0226->a, U+0227->a, U+0228->e, U+0229->e, U+022A->o,        U+022B->o, U+022C->o, U+022D->o, U+022E->o, U+022F->o, U+0230->o,        U+0231->o, U+0232->y, U+0233->y, U+1E00->a, U+1E01->a, U+1E02->b,        U+1E03->b, U+1E04->b, U+1E05->b, U+1E06->b, U+1E07->b, U+1E08->c,        U+1E09->c, U+1E0A->d, U+1E0B->d, U+1E0C->d, U+1E0D->d, U+1E0E->d,        U+1E0F->d, U+1E10->d, U+1E11->d, U+1E12->d, U+1E13->d, U+1E14->e,        U+1E15->e, U+1E16->e, U+1E17->e, U+1E18->e, U+1E19->e, U+1E1A->e,        U+1E1B->e, U+1E1C->e, U+1E1D->e, U+1E1E->f, U+1E1F->f, U+1E20->g,        U+1E21->g, U+1E22->h, U+1E23->h, U+1E24->h, U+1E25->h, U+1E26->h,        U+1E27->h, U+1E28->h, U+1E29->h, U+1E2A->h, U+1E2B->h, U+1E2C->i,        U+1E2D->i, U+1E2E->i, U+1E2F->i, U+1E30->k, U+1E31->k, U+1E32->k,        U+1E33->k, U+1E34->k, U+1E35->k, U+1E36->l, U+1E37->l, U+1E38->l,        U+1E39->l, U+1E3A->l, U+1E3B->l, U+1E3C->l, U+1E3D->l, U+1E3E->m,        U+1E3F->m, U+1E40->m, U+1E41->m, U+1E42->m, U+1E43->m, U+1E44->n,        U+1E45->n, U+1E46->n, U+1E47->n, U+1E48->n, U+1E49->n, U+1E4A->n,        U+1E4B->n, U+1E4C->o, U+1E4D->o, U+1E4E->o, U+1E4F->o, U+1E50->o,        U+1E51->o, U+1E52->o, U+1E53->o, U+1E54->p, U+1E55->p, U+1E56->p,        U+1E57->p, U+1E58->r, U+1E59->r, U+1E5A->r, U+1E5B->r, U+1E5C->r,        U+1E5D->r, U+1E5E->r, U+1E5F->r, U+1E60->s, U+1E61->s, U+1E62->s,        U+1E63->s, U+1E64->s, U+1E65->s, U+1E66->s, U+1E67->s, U+1E68->s,        U+1E69->s, U+1E6A->t, U+1E6B->t, U+1E6C->t, U+1E6D->t, U+1E6E->t,        U+1E6F->t, U+1E70->t, U+1E71->t, U+1E72->u, U+1E73->u, U+1E74->u,        U+1E75->u, U+1E76->u, U+1E77->u, U+1E78->u, U+1E79->u, U+1E7A->u,        U+1E7B->u, U+1E7C->v, U+1E7D->v, U+1E7E->v, U+1E7F->v, U+1E80->w,        U+1E81->w, U+1E82->w, U+1E83->w, U+1E84->w, U+1E85->w, U+1E86->w,        U+1E87->w, U+1E88->w, U+1E89->w, U+1E8A->x, U+1E8B->x, U+1E8C->x,        U+1E8D->x, U+1E8E->y, U+1E8F->y, U+1E96->h, U+1E97->t, U+1E98->w,        U+1E99->y, U+1EA0->a, U+1EA1->a, U+1EA2->a, U+1EA3->a, U+1EA4->a,        U+1EA5->a, U+1EA6->a, U+1EA7->a, U+1EA8->a, U+1EA9->a, U+1EAA->a,        U+1EAB->a, U+1EAC->a, U+1EAD->a, U+1EAE->a, U+1EAF->a, U+1EB0->a,        U+1EB1->a, U+1EB2->a, U+1EB3->a, U+1EB4->a, U+1EB5->a, U+1EB6->a,        U+1EB7->a, U+1EB8->e, U+1EB9->e, U+1EBA->e, U+1EBB->e, U+1EBC->e,        U+1EBD->e, U+1EBE->e, U+1EBF->e, U+1EC0->e, U+1EC1->e, U+1EC2->e,        U+1EC3->e, U+1EC4->e, U+1EC5->e, U+1EC6->e, U+1EC7->e, U+1EC8->i,        U+1EC9->i, U+1ECA->i, U+1ECB->i, U+1ECC->o, U+1ECD->o, U+1ECE->o,        U+1ECF->o, U+1ED0->o, U+1ED1->o, U+1ED2->o, U+1ED3->o, U+1ED4->o,        U+1ED5->o, U+1ED6->o, U+1ED7->o, U+1ED8->o, U+1ED9->o, U+1EDA->o,        U+1EDB->o, U+1EDC->o, U+1EDD->o, U+1EDE->o, U+1EDF->o, U+1EE0->o,        U+1EE1->o, U+1EE2->o, U+1EE3->o, U+1EE4->u, U+1EE5->u, U+1EE6->u,        U+1EE7->u, U+1EE8->u, U+1EE9->u, U+1EEA->u, U+1EEB->u, U+1EEC->u,        U+1EED->u, U+1EEE->u, U+1EEF->u, U+1EF0->u, U+1EF1->u, U+1EF2->y,        U+1EF3->y, U+1EF4->y, U+1EF5->y, U+1EF6->y, U+1EF7->y, U+1EF8->y,        U+1EF9->y"
```

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2):

This might help.  The sphinx documentation is actually pretty good:

http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#charsets

In particular, these two settings should give you what you're looking for:

> [charset_type](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-type) specifies whether the
>   document encoding is single-byte
>   (SBCS) or UTF-8. [charset_table](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table)
>   specifies the table that maps letter
>   characters to their case folded
>   versions

Comment: Thank you. I guess my problem is I don't know how to properly configure the sphinx.conf file. I mean, I don't know exactly how to write within each index statement, and whether I have to write it there or simply write "define_index do indexes title end" at a ruby model.

Comment: All you need to do in your models is define the index.  If you want to change the configuration of sphinx/thinking_sphinx globally, you should be able to put those settings in /config/sphinx.yml (more information here: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html).  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Hey, you know what? Incidently, we have the exact opposite problems: I have been running on a charset that specifically differs spanish characters and accents and I have this far been unable to get Sphinx to treat accented letters as non-accented.

Imagine my surprise when I hit on this thread. I changed my charset configuration for yours and it worked exactly as intended. Your problem was my solution and I think that my problem is yours.

Here is my old charset config that makes a difference between "vídeo" and "video"

```
charset_table = \
U+00C0->a, U+00C1->a, U+00C2->a, U+00C3->a, U+00C4->a, U+00C5->a, U+00E0->a, U+00E1->a, U+00E2->a, U+00E3->a, U+00E4->a, U+00E5->a, U+0100->a, U+0101->a, U+0102->a, U+0103->a, U+010300->a, U+0104->a, U+0105->a, U+01CD->a, U+01CE->a, U+01DE->a, U+01DF->a,  \
U+01E0->a, U+01E1->a, U+01FA->a, U+01FB->a, U+0200->a, U+0201->a, U+0202->a, U+0203->a, U+0226->a, U+0227->a, U+023A->a, U+0250->a, U+04D0->a, U+04D1->a, U+1D2C->a, U+1D43->a, U+1D44->a, U+1D8F->a, U+1E00->a, U+1E01->a, U+1E9A->a, U+1EA0->a, U+1EA1->a,  \
U+1EA2->a, U+1EA3->a, U+1EA4->a, U+1EA5->a, U+1EA6->a, U+1EA7->a, U+1EA8->a, U+1EA9->a, U+1EAA->a, U+1EAB->a, U+1EAC->a, U+1EAD->a, U+1EAE->a, U+1EAF->a, U+1EB0->a, U+1EB1->a, U+1EB2->a, U+1EB3->a, U+1EB4->a, U+1EB5->a, U+1EB6->a, U+1EB7->a, U+2090->a,  \
U+2C65->a, U+0180->b, U+0181->b, U+0182->b, U+0183->b, U+0243->b, U+0253->b, U+0299->b, U+16D2->b, U+1D03->b, U+1D2E->b, U+1D2F->b, U+1D47->b, U+1D6C->b, U+1D80->b, U+1E02->b, U+1E03->b, U+1E04->b, U+1E05->b, U+1E06->b, U+1E07->b, U+00C7->c, U+00E7->c,  \
U+0106->c, U+0107->c, U+0108->c, U+0109->c, U+010A->c, U+010B->c, U+010C->c, U+010D->c, U+0187->c, U+0188->c, U+023B->c, U+023C->c, U+0255->c, U+0297->c, U+1D9C->c, U+1D9D->c, U+1E08->c, U+1E09->c, U+212D->c, U+2184->c, U+010E->d, U+010F->d, U+0110->d,  \
U+0111->d, U+0189->d, U+018A->d, U+018B->d, U+018C->d, U+01C5->d, U+01F2->d, U+0221->d, U+0256->d, U+0257->d, U+1D05->d, U+1D30->d, U+1D48->d, U+1D6D->d, U+1D81->d, U+1D91->d, U+1E0A->d, U+1E0B->d, U+1E0C->d, U+1E0D->d, U+1E0E->d, U+1E0F->d, U+1E10->d,  \
U+1E11->d, U+1E12->d, U+1E13->d, U+00C8->e, U+00C9->e, U+00CA->e, U+00CB->e, U+00E8->e, U+00E9->e, U+00EA->e, U+00EB->e, U+0112->e, U+0113->e, U+0114->e, U+0115->e, U+0116->e, U+0117->e, U+0118->e, U+0119->e, U+011A->e, U+011B->e, U+018E->e, U+0190->e,  \
U+01DD->e, U+0204->e, U+0205->e, U+0206->e, U+0207->e, U+0228->e, U+0229->e, U+0246->e, U+0247->e, U+0258->e, U+025B->e, U+025C->e, U+025D->e, U+025E->e, U+029A->e, U+1D07->e, U+1D08->e, U+1D31->e, U+1D32->e, U+1D49->e, U+1D4B->e, U+1D4C->e, U+1D92->e,  \
U+1D93->e, U+1D94->e, U+1D9F->e, U+1E14->e, U+1E15->e, U+1E16->e, U+1E17->e, U+1E18->e, U+1E19->e, U+1E1A->e, U+1E1B->e, U+1E1C->e, U+1E1D->e, U+1EB8->e, U+1EB9->e, U+1EBA->e, U+1EBB->e, U+1EBC->e, U+1EBD->e, U+1EBE->e, U+1EBF->e, U+1EC0->e, U+1EC1->e,  \
U+1EC2->e, U+1EC3->e, U+1EC4->e, U+1EC5->e, U+1EC6->e, U+1EC7->e, U+2091->e, U+0191->f, U+0192->f, U+1D6E->f, U+1D82->f, U+1DA0->f, U+1E1E->f, U+1E1F->f, U+011C->g, U+011D->g, U+011E->g, U+011F->g, U+0120->g, U+0121->g, U+0122->g, U+0123->g, U+0193->g,  \
U+01E4->g, U+01E5->g, U+01E6->g, U+01E7->g, U+01F4->g, U+01F5->g, U+0260->g, U+0261->g, U+0262->g, U+029B->g, U+1D33->g, U+1D4D->g, U+1D77->g, U+1D79->g, U+1D83->g, U+1DA2->g, U+1E20->g, U+1E21->g, U+0124->h, U+0125->h, U+0126->h, U+0127->h, U+021E->h,  \
U+021F->h, U+0265->h, U+0266->h, U+029C->h, U+02AE->h, U+02AF->h, U+02B0->h, U+02B1->h, U+1D34->h, U+1DA3->h, U+1E22->h, U+1E23->h, U+1E24->h, U+1E25->h, U+1E26->h, U+1E27->h, U+1E28->h, U+1E29->h, U+1E2A->h, U+1E2B->h, U+1E96->h, U+210C->h, U+2C67->h,  \
U+2C68->h, U+2C75->h, U+2C76->h, U+00CC->i, U+00CD->i, U+00CE->i, U+00CF->i, U+00EC->i, U+00ED->i, U+00EE->i, U+00EF->i, U+010309->i, U+0128->i, U+0129->i, U+012A->i, U+012B->i, U+012C->i, U+012D->i, U+012E->i, U+012F->i, U+0130->i, U+0131->i, U+0197->i,  \
U+01CF->i, U+01D0->i, U+0208->i, U+0209->i, U+020A->i, U+020B->i, U+0268->i, U+026A->i, U+040D->i, U+0418->i, U+0419->i, U+0438->i, U+0439->i, U+0456->i, U+1D09->i, U+1D35->i, U+1D4E->i, U+1D62->i, U+1D7B->i, U+1D96->i, U+1DA4->i, U+1DA6->i, U+1DA7->i,  \
U+1E2C->i, U+1E2D->i, U+1E2E->i, U+1E2F->i, U+1EC8->i, U+1EC9->i, U+1ECA->i, U+1ECB->i, U+2071->i, U+2111->i, U+0134->j, U+0135->j, U+01C8->j, U+01CB->j, U+01F0->j, U+0237->j, U+0248->j, U+0249->j, U+025F->j, U+0284->j, U+029D->j, U+02B2->j, U+1D0A->j,  \
U+1D36->j, U+1DA1->j, U+1DA8->j, U+0136->k, U+0137->k, U+0198->k, U+0199->k, U+01E8->k, U+01E9->k, U+029E->k, U+1D0B->k, U+1D37->k, U+1D4F->k, U+1D84->k, U+1E30->k, U+1E31->k, U+1E32->k, U+1E33->k, U+1E34->k, U+1E35->k, U+2C69->k, U+2C6A->k, U+0139->l,  \
U+013A->l, U+013B->l, U+013C->l, U+013D->l, U+013E->l, U+013F->l, U+0140->l, U+0141->l, U+0142->l, U+019A->l, U+01C8->l, U+0234->l, U+023D->l, U+026B->l, U+026C->l, U+026D->l, U+029F->l, U+02E1->l, U+1D0C->l, U+1D38->l, U+1D85->l, U+1DA9->l, U+1DAA->l,  \
U+1DAB->l, U+1E36->l, U+1E37->l, U+1E38->l, U+1E39->l, U+1E3A->l, U+1E3B->l, U+1E3C->l, U+1E3D->l, U+2C60->l, U+2C61->l, U+2C62->l, U+019C->m, U+026F->m, U+0270->m, U+0271->m, U+1D0D->m, U+1D1F->m, U+1D39->m, U+1D50->m, U+1D5A->m, U+1D6F->m, U+1D86->m,  \
U+1DAC->m, U+1DAD->m, U+1E3E->m, U+1E3F->m, U+1E40->m, U+1E41->m, U+1E42->m, U+1E43->m, U+00D1->n, U+00F1->n, U+0143->n, U+0144->n, U+0145->n, U+0146->n, U+0147->n, U+0148->n, U+0149->n, U+019D->n, U+019E->n, U+01CB->n, U+01F8->n, U+01F9->n, U+0220->n,  \
U+0235->n, U+0272->n, U+0273->n, U+0274->n, U+1D0E->n, U+1D3A->n, U+1D3B->n, U+1D70->n, U+1D87->n, U+1DAE->n, U+1DAF->n, U+1DB0->n, U+1E44->n, U+1E45->n, U+1E46->n, U+1E47->n, U+1E48->n, U+1E49->n, U+1E4A->n, U+1E4B->n, U+207F->n, U+00D2->o, U+00D3->o,  \
U+00D4->o, U+00D5->o, U+00D6->o, U+00D8->o, U+00F2->o, U+00F3->o, U+00F4->o, U+00F5->o, U+00F6->o, U+00F8->o, U+01030F->o, U+014C->o, U+014D->o, U+014E->o, U+014F->o, U+0150->o, U+0151->o, U+0186->o, U+019F->o, U+01A0->o, U+01A1->o, U+01D1->o, U+01D2->o,  \
U+01EA->o, U+01EB->o, U+01EC->o, U+01ED->o, U+01FE->o, U+01FF->o, U+020C->o, U+020D->o, U+020E->o, U+020F->o, U+022A->o, U+022B->o, U+022C->o, U+022D->o, U+022E->o, U+022F->o, U+0230->o, U+0231->o, U+0254->o, U+0275->o, U+043E->o, U+04E6->o, U+04E7->o,  \
U+04E8->o, U+04E9->o, U+04EA->o, U+04EB->o, U+1D0F->o, U+1D10->o, U+1D11->o, U+1D12->o, U+1D13->o, U+1D16->o, U+1D17->o, U+1D3C->o, U+1D52->o, U+1D53->o, U+1D54->o, U+1D55->o, U+1D97->o, U+1DB1->o, U+1E4C->o, U+1E4D->o, U+1E4E->o, U+1E4F->o, U+1E50->o,  \
U+1E51->o, U+1E52->o, U+1E53->o, U+1ECC->o, U+1ECD->o, U+1ECE->o, U+1ECF->o, U+1ED0->o, U+1ED1->o, U+1ED2->o, U+1ED3->o, U+1ED4->o, U+1ED5->o, U+1ED6->o, U+1ED7->o, U+1ED8->o, U+1ED9->o, U+1EDA->o, U+1EDB->o, U+1EDC->o, U+1EDD->o, U+1EDE->o, U+1EDF->o,  \
U+1EE0->o, U+1EE1->o, U+1EE2->o, U+1EE3->o, U+2092->o, U+2C9E->o, U+2C9F->o, U+01A4->p, U+01A5->p, U+1D18->p, U+1D3E->p, U+1D56->p, U+1D71->p, U+1D7D->p, U+1D88->p, U+1E54->p, U+1E55->p, U+1E56->p, U+1E57->p, U+2C63->p, U+024A->q, U+024B->q, U+02A0->q,  \
U+0154->r, U+0155->r, U+0156->r, U+0157->r, U+0158->r, U+0159->r, U+0210->r, U+0211->r, U+0212->r, U+0213->r, U+024C->r, U+024D->r, U+0279->r, U+027A->r, U+027B->r, U+027C->r, U+027D->r, U+027E->r, U+027F->r, U+0280->r, U+0281->r, U+02B3->r, U+02B4->r,  \
U+02B5->r, U+02B6->r, U+1D19->r, U+1D1A->r, U+1D3F->r, U+1D63->r, U+1D72->r, U+1D73->r, U+1D89->r, U+1DCA->r, U+1E58->r, U+1E59->r, U+1E5A->r, U+1E5B->r, U+1E5C->r, U+1E5D->r, U+1E5E->r, U+1E5F->r, U+211C->r, U+2C64->r, U+00DF->s, U+015A->s, U+015B->s,  \
U+015C->s, U+015D->s, U+015E->s, U+015F->s, U+0160->s, U+0161->s, U+017F->s, U+0218->s, U+0219->s, U+023F->s, U+0282->s, U+02E2->s, U+1D74->s, U+1D8A->s, U+1DB3->s, U+1E60->s, U+1E61->s, U+1E62->s, U+1E63->s, U+1E64->s, U+1E65->s, U+1E66->s, U+1E67->s,  \
U+1E68->s, U+1E69->s, U+1E9B->s, U+0162->t, U+0163->t, U+0164->t, U+0165->t, U+0166->t, U+0167->t, U+01AB->t, U+01AC->t, U+01AD->t, U+01AE->t, U+021A->t, U+021B->t, U+0236->t, U+023E->t, U+0287->t, U+0288->t, U+1D1B->t, U+1D40->t, U+1D57->t, U+1D75->t,  \
U+1DB5->t, U+1E6A->t, U+1E6B->t, U+1E6C->t, U+1E6D->t, U+1E6E->t, U+1E6F->t, U+1E70->t, U+1E71->t, U+1E97->t, U+2C66->t, U+00D9->u, U+00DA->u, U+00DB->u, U+00DC->u, U+00F9->u, U+00FA->u, U+00FB->u, U+00FC->u, U+010316->u, U+0168->u, U+0169->u, U+016A->u,  \
U+016B->u, U+016C->u, U+016D->u, U+016E->u, U+016F->u, U+0170->u, U+0171->u, U+0172->u, U+0173->u, U+01AF->u, U+01B0->u, U+01D3->u, U+01D4->u, U+01D5->u, U+01D6->u, U+01D7->u, U+01D8->u, U+01D9->u, U+01DA->u, U+01DB->u, U+01DC->u, U+0214->u, U+0215->u,  \
U+0216->u, U+0217->u, U+0244->u, U+0289->u, U+1D1C->u, U+1D1D->u, U+1D1E->u, U+1D41->u, U+1D58->u, U+1D59->u, U+1D64->u, U+1D7E->u, U+1D99->u, U+1DB6->u, U+1DB8->u, U+1E72->u, U+1E73->u, U+1E74->u, U+1E75->u, U+1E76->u, U+1E77->u, U+1E78->u, U+1E79->u,  \
U+1E7A->u, U+1E7B->u, U+1EE4->u, U+1EE5->u, U+1EE6->u, U+1EE7->u, U+1EE8->u, U+1EE9->u, U+1EEA->u, U+1EEB->u, U+1EEC->u, U+1EED->u, U+1EEE->u, U+1EEF->u, U+1EF0->u, U+1EF1->u, U+01B2->v, U+0245->v, U+028B->v, U+028C->v, U+1D20->v, U+1D5B->v, U+1D65->v,  \
U+1D8C->v, U+1DB9->v, U+1DBA->v, U+1E7C->v, U+1E7D->v, U+1E7E->v, U+1E7F->v, U+2C74->v, U+0174->w, U+0175->w, U+028D->w, U+02B7->w, U+1D21->w, U+1D42->w, U+1E80->w, U+1E81->w, U+1E82->w, U+1E83->w, U+1E84->w, U+1E85->w, U+1E86->w, U+1E87->w, U+1E88->w,  \
U+1E89->w, U+1E98->w, U+02E3->x, U+1D8D->x, U+1E8A->x, U+1E8B->x, U+1E8C->x, U+1E8D->x, U+2093->x, U+00DD->y, U+00FD->y, U+00FF->y, U+0176->y, U+0177->y, U+0178->y, U+01B3->y, U+01B4->y, U+0232->y, U+0233->y, U+024E->y, U+024F->y, U+028E->y, U+028F->y,  \
U+02B8->y, U+1E8E->y, U+1E8F->y, U+1E99->y, U+1EF2->y, U+1EF3->y, U+1EF4->y, U+1EF5->y, U+1EF6->y, U+1EF7->y, U+1EF8->y, U+1EF9->y, U+0179->z, U+017A->z, U+017B->z, U+017C->z, U+017D->z, U+017E->z, U+01B5->z, U+01B6->z, U+0224->z, U+0225->z, U+0240->z,  \
U+0290->z, U+0291->z, U+1D22->z, U+1D76->z, U+1D8E->z, U+1DBB->z, U+1DBC->z, U+1DBD->z, U+1E90->z, U+1E91->z, U+1E92->z, U+1E93->z, U+1E94->z, U+1E95->z, U+2128->z, U+2C6B->z, U+2C6C->z, U+00C6->U+00E6, U+01E2->U+00E6, U+01E3->U+00E6, U+01FC->U+00E6,  \
U+01FD->U+00E6, U+1D01->U+00E6, U+1D02->U+00E6, U+1D2D->U+00E6, U+1D46->U+00E6, U+00E6, U+0622->U+0627, U+0623->U+0627, U+0624->U+0648, U+0625->U+0627, U+0626->U+064A, U+06C0->U+06D5, U+06C2->U+06C1, U+06D3->U+06D2, U+FB50->U+0671, U+FB51->U+0671, U+FB52->U+067B,  \
U+FB53->U+067B, U+FB54->U+067B, U+FB56->U+067E, U+FB57->U+067E, U+FB58->U+067E, U+FB5A->U+0680, U+FB5B->U+0680, U+FB5C->U+0680, U+FB5E->U+067A, U+FB5F->U+067A, U+FB60->U+067A, U+FB62->U+067F, U+FB63->U+067F, U+FB64->U+067F, U+FB66->U+0679, U+FB67->U+0679,  \
U+FB68->U+0679, U+FB6A->U+06A4, U+FB6B->U+06A4, U+FB6C->U+06A4, U+FB6E->U+06A6, U+FB6F->U+06A6, U+FB70->U+06A6, U+FB72->U+0684, U+FB73->U+0684, U+FB74->U+0684, U+FB76->U+0683, U+FB77->U+0683, U+FB78->U+0683, U+FB7A->U+0686, U+FB7B->U+0686, U+FB7C->U+0686,  \
U+FB7E->U+0687, U+FB7F->U+0687, U+FB80->U+0687, U+FB82->U+068D, U+FB83->U+068D, U+FB84->U+068C, U+FB85->U+068C, U+FB86->U+068E, U+FB87->U+068E, U+FB88->U+0688, U+FB89->U+0688, U+FB8A->U+0698, U+FB8B->U+0698, U+FB8C->U+0691, U+FB8D->U+0691, U+FB8E->U+06A9,  \
U+FB8F->U+06A9, U+FB90->U+06A9, U+FB92->U+06AF, U+FB93->U+06AF, U+FB94->U+06AF, U+FB96->U+06B3, U+FB97->U+06B3, U+FB98->U+06B3, U+FB9A->U+06B1, U+FB9B->U+06B1, U+FB9C->U+06B1, U+FB9E->U+06BA, U+FB9F->U+06BA, U+FBA0->U+06BB, U+FBA1->U+06BB, U+FBA2->U+06BB,  \
U+FBA4->U+06C0, U+FBA5->U+06C0, U+FBA6->U+06C1, U+FBA7->U+06C1, U+FBA8->U+06C1, U+FBAA->U+06BE, U+FBAB->U+06BE, U+FBAC->U+06BE, U+FBAE->U+06D2, U+FBAF->U+06D2, U+FBB0->U+06D3, U+FBB1->U+06D3, U+FBD3->U+06AD, U+FBD4->U+06AD, U+FBD5->U+06AD, U+FBD7->U+06C7,  \
U+FBD8->U+06C7, U+FBD9->U+06C6, U+FBDA->U+06C6, U+FBDB->U+06C8, U+FBDC->U+06C8, U+FBDD->U+0677, U+FBDE->U+06CB, U+FBDF->U+06CB, U+FBE0->U+06C5, U+FBE1->U+06C5, U+FBE2->U+06C9, U+FBE3->U+06C9, U+FBE4->U+06D0, U+FBE5->U+06D0, U+FBE6->U+06D0, U+FBE8->U+0649,  \
U+FBFC->U+06CC, U+FBFD->U+06CC, U+FBFE->U+06CC, U+0621, U+0627..U+063A, U+0641..U+064A, U+0660..U+0669, U+066E, U+066F, U+0671..U+06BF, U+06C1, U+06C3..U+06D2, U+06D5, U+06EE..U+06FC, U+06FF, U+0750..U+076D, U+FB55, U+FB59, U+FB5D, U+FB61, U+FB65, U+FB69,  \
U+FB6D, U+FB71, U+FB75, U+FB79, U+FB7D, U+FB81, U+FB91, U+FB95, U+FB99, U+FB9D, U+FBA3, U+FBA9, U+FBAD, U+FBD6, U+FBE7, U+FBE9, U+FBFF, U+0531..U+0556->U+0561..U+0586, U+0561..U+0586, U+0587, U+09DC->U+09A1, U+09DD->U+09A2, U+09DF->U+09AF, U+09F0->U+09AC,  \
U+09F1->U+09AC, U+0985..U+0990, U+0993..U+09B0, U+09B2, U+09B6..U+09B9, U+09CE, U+09E0, U+09E1, U+09E6..U+09EF, U+F900->U+8C48, U+F901->U+66F4, U+F902->U+8ECA, U+F903->U+8CC8, U+F904->U+6ED1, U+F905->U+4E32, U+F906->U+53E5, U+F907->U+9F9C, U+F908->U+9F9C,  \
U+F909->U+5951, U+F90A->U+91D1, U+F90B->U+5587, U+F90C->U+5948, U+F90D->U+61F6, U+F90E->U+7669, U+F90F->U+7F85, U+F910->U+863F, U+F911->U+87BA, U+F912->U+88F8, U+F913->U+908F, U+F914->U+6A02, U+F915->U+6D1B, U+F916->U+70D9, U+F917->U+73DE, U+F918->U+843D,  \
U+F919->U+916A, U+F91A->U+99F1, U+F91B->U+4E82, U+F91C->U+5375, U+F91D->U+6B04, U+F91E->U+721B, U+F91F->U+862D, U+F920->U+9E1E, U+F921->U+5D50, U+F922->U+6FEB, U+F923->U+85CD, U+F924->U+8964, U+F925->U+62C9, U+F926->U+81D8, U+F927->U+881F, U+F928->U+5ECA,  \
U+F929->U+6717, U+F92A->U+6D6A, U+F92B->U+72FC, U+F92C->U+90CE, U+F92D->U+4F86, U+F92E->U+51B7, U+F92F->U+52DE, U+F930->U+64C4, U+F931->U+6AD3, U+F932->U+7210, U+F933->U+76E7, U+F934->U+8001, U+F935->U+8606, U+F936->U+865C, U+F937->U+8DEF, U+F938->U+9732,  \
U+F939->U+9B6F, U+F93A->U+9DFA, U+F93B->U+788C, U+F93C->U+797F, U+F93D->U+7DA0, U+F93E->U+83C9, U+F93F->U+9304, U+F940->U+9E7F, U+F941->U+8AD6, U+F942->U+58DF, U+F943->U+5F04, U+F944->U+7C60, U+F945->U+807E, U+F946->U+7262, U+F947->U+78CA, U+F948->U+8CC2,  \
U+F949->U+96F7, U+F94A->U+58D8, U+F94B->U+5C62, U+F94C->U+6A13, U+F94D->U+6DDA, U+F94E->U+6F0F, U+F94F->U+7D2F, U+F950->U+7E37, U+F951->U+964B, U+F952->U+52D2, U+F953->U+808B, U+F954->U+51DC, U+F955->U+51CC, U+F956->U+7A1C, U+F957->U+7DBE, U+F958->U+83F1,  \
U+F959->U+9675, U+F95A->U+8B80, U+F95B->U+62CF, U+F95C->U+6A02, U+F95D->U+8AFE, U+F95E->U+4E39, U+F95F->U+5BE7, U+F960->U+6012, U+F961->U+7387, U+F962->U+7570, U+F963->U+5317, U+F964->U+78FB, U+F965->U+4FBF, U+F966->U+5FA9, U+F967->U+4E0D, U+F968->U+6CCC,  \
U+F969->U+6578, U+F96A->U+7D22, U+F96B->U+53C3, U+F96C->U+585E, U+F96D->U+7701, U+F96E->U+8449, U+F96F->U+8AAA, U+F970->U+6BBA, U+F971->U+8FB0, U+F972->U+6C88, U+F973->U+62FE, U+F974->U+82E5, U+F975->U+63A0, U+F976->U+7565, U+F977->U+4EAE, U+F978->U+5169,  \
U+F979->U+51C9, U+F97A->U+6881, U+F97B->U+7CE7, U+F97C->U+826F, U+F97D->U+8AD2, U+F97E->U+91CF, U+F97F->U+52F5, U+F980->U+5442, U+F981->U+5973, U+F982->U+5EEC, U+F983->U+65C5, U+F984->U+6FFE, U+F985->U+792A, U+F986->U+95AD, U+F987->U+9A6A, U+F988->U+9E97,  \
U+F989->U+9ECE, U+F98A->U+529B, U+F98B->U+66C6, U+F98C->U+6B77, U+F98D->U+8F62, U+F98E->U+5E74, U+F98F->U+6190, U+F990->U+6200, U+F991->U+649A, U+F992->U+6F23, U+F993->U+7149, U+F994->U+7489, U+F995->U+79CA, U+F996->U+7DF4, U+F997->U+806F, U+F998->U+8F26,  \
U+F999->U+84EE, U+F99A->U+9023, U+F99B->U+934A, U+F99C->U+5217, U+F99D->U+52A3, U+F99E->U+54BD, U+F99F->U+70C8, U+F9A0->U+88C2, U+F9A1->U+8AAA, U+F9A2->U+5EC9, U+F9A3->U+5FF5, U+F9A4->U+637B, U+F9A5->U+6BAE, U+F9A6->U+7C3E, U+F9A7->U+7375, U+F9A8->U+4EE4,  \
U+F9A9->U+56F9, U+F9AA->U+5BE7, U+F9AB->U+5DBA, U+F9AC->U+601C, U+F9AD->U+73B2, U+F9AE->U+7469, U+F9AF->U+7F9A, U+F9B0->U+8046, U+F9B1->U+9234, U+F9B2->U+96F6, U+F9B3->U+9748, U+F9B4->U+9818, U+F9B5->U+4F8B, U+F9B6->U+79AE, U+F9B7->U+91B4, U+F9B8->U+96B8,  \
U+F9B9->U+60E1, U+F9BA->U+4E86, U+F9BB->U+50DA, U+F9BC->U+5BEE, U+F9BD->U+5C3F, U+F9BE->U+6599, U+F9BF->U+6A02, U+F9C0->U+71CE, U+F9C1->U+7642, U+F9C2->U+84FC, U+F9C3->U+907C, U+F9C4->U+9F8D, U+F9C5->U+6688, U+F9C6->U+962E, U+F9C7->U+5289, U+F9C8->U+677B,  \
U+F9C9->U+67F3, U+F9CA->U+6D41, U+F9CB->U+6E9C, U+F9CC->U+7409, U+F9CD->U+7559, U+F9CE->U+786B, U+F9CF->U+7D10, U+F9D0->U+985E, U+F9D1->U+516D, U+F9D2->U+622E, U+F9D3->U+9678, U+F9D4->U+502B, U+F9D5->U+5D19, U+F9D6->U+6DEA, U+F9D7->U+8F2A, U+F9D8->U+5F8B,  \
U+F9D9->U+6144, U+F9DA->U+6817, U+F9DB->U+7387, U+F9DC->U+9686, U+F9DD->U+5229, U+F9DE->U+540F, U+F9DF->U+5C65, U+F9E0->U+6613, U+F9E1->U+674E, U+F9E2->U+68A8, U+F9E3->U+6CE5, U+F9E4->U+7406, U+F9E5->U+75E2, U+F9E6->U+7F79, U+F9E7->U+88CF, U+F9E8->U+88E1,  \
U+F9E9->U+91CC, U+F9EA->U+96E2, U+F9EB->U+533F, U+F9EC->U+6EBA, U+F9ED->U+541D, U+F9EE->U+71D0, U+F9EF->U+7498, U+F9F0->U+85FA, U+F9F1->U+96A3, U+F9F2->U+9C57, U+F9F3->U+9E9F, U+F9F4->U+6797, U+F9F5->U+6DCB, U+F9F6->U+81E8, U+F9F7->U+7ACB, U+F9F8->U+7B20,  \
U+F9F9->U+7C92, U+F9FA->U+72C0, U+F9FB->U+7099, U+F9FC->U+8B58, U+F9FD->U+4EC0, U+F9FE->U+8336, U+F9FF->U+523A, U+FA00->U+5207, U+FA01->U+5EA6, U+FA02->U+62D3, U+FA03->U+7CD6, U+FA04->U+5B85, U+FA05->U+6D1E, U+FA06->U+66B4, U+FA07->U+8F3B, U+FA08->U+884C,  \
U+FA09->U+964D, U+FA0A->U+898B, U+FA0B->U+5ED3, U+FA0C->U+5140, U+FA0D->U+55C0, U+FA10->U+585A, U+FA12->U+6674, U+FA15->U+51DE, U+FA16->U+732A, U+FA17->U+76CA, U+FA18->U+793C, U+FA19->U+795E, U+FA1A->U+7965, U+FA1B->U+798F, U+FA1C->U+9756, U+FA1D->U+7CBE,  \
U+FA1E->U+7FBD, U+FA20->U+8612, U+FA22->U+8AF8, U+FA25->U+9038, U+FA26->U+90FD, U+FA2A->U+98EF, U+FA2B->U+98FC, U+FA2C->U+9928, U+FA2D->U+9DB4, U+FA30->U+4FAE, U+FA31->U+50E7, U+FA32->U+514D, U+FA33->U+52C9, U+FA34->U+52E4, U+FA35->U+5351, U+FA36->U+559D,  \
U+FA37->U+5606, U+FA38->U+5668, U+FA39->U+5840, U+FA3A->U+58A8, U+FA3B->U+5C64, U+FA3C->U+5C6E, U+FA3D->U+6094, U+FA3E->U+6168, U+FA3F->U+618E, U+FA40->U+61F2, U+FA41->U+654F, U+FA42->U+65E2, U+FA43->U+6691, U+FA44->U+6885, U+FA45->U+6D77, U+FA46->U+6E1A,  \
U+FA47->U+6F22, U+FA48->U+716E, U+FA49->U+722B, U+FA4A->U+7422, U+FA4B->U+7891, U+FA4C->U+793E, U+FA4D->U+7949, U+FA4E->U+7948, U+FA4F->U+7950, U+FA50->U+7956, U+FA51->U+795D, U+FA52->U+798D, U+FA53->U+798E, U+FA54->U+7A40, U+FA55->U+7A81, U+FA56->U+7BC0,  \
U+FA57->U+7DF4, U+FA58->U+7E09, U+FA59->U+7E41, U+FA5A->U+7F72, U+FA5B->U+8005, U+FA5C->U+81ED, U+FA5D->U+8279, U+FA5E->U+8279, U+FA5F->U+8457, U+FA60->U+8910, U+FA61->U+8996, U+FA62->U+8B01, U+FA63->U+8B39, U+FA64->U+8CD3, U+FA65->U+8D08, U+FA66->U+8FB6,  \
U+FA67->U+9038, U+FA68->U+96E3, U+FA69->U+97FF, U+FA6A->U+983B, U+FA70->U+4E26, U+FA71->U+51B5, U+FA72->U+5168, U+FA73->U+4F80, U+FA74->U+5145, U+FA75->U+5180, U+FA76->U+52C7, U+FA77->U+52FA, U+FA78->U+559D, U+FA79->U+5555, U+FA7A->U+5599, U+FA7B->U+55E2,  \
U+FA7C->U+585A, U+FA7D->U+58B3, U+FA7E->U+5944, U+FA7F->U+5954, U+FA80->U+5A62, U+FA81->U+5B28, U+FA82->U+5ED2, U+FA83->U+5ED9, U+FA84->U+5F69, U+FA85->U+5FAD, U+FA86->U+60D8, U+FA87->U+614E, U+FA88->U+6108, U+FA89->U+618E, U+FA8A->U+6160, U+FA8B->U+61F2,  \
U+FA8C->U+6234, U+FA8D->U+63C4, U+FA8E->U+641C, U+FA8F->U+6452, U+FA90->U+6556, U+FA91->U+6674, U+FA92->U+6717, U+FA93->U+671B, U+FA94->U+6756, U+FA95->U+6B79, U+FA96->U+6BBA, U+FA97->U+6D41, U+FA98->U+6EDB, U+FA99->U+6ECB, U+FA9A->U+6F22, U+FA9B->U+701E,  \
U+FA9C->U+716E, U+FA9D->U+77A7, U+FA9E->U+7235, U+FA9F->U+72AF, U+FAA0->U+732A, U+FAA1->U+7471, U+FAA2->U+7506, U+FAA3->U+753B, U+FAA4->U+761D, U+FAA5->U+761F, U+FAA6->U+76CA, U+FAA7->U+76DB, U+FAA8->U+76F4, U+FAA9->U+774A, U+FAAA->U+7740, U+FAAB->U+78CC,  \
U+FAAC->U+7AB1, U+FAAD->U+7BC0, U+FAAE->U+7C7B, U+FAAF->U+7D5B, U+FAB0->U+7DF4, U+FAB1->U+7F3E, U+FAB2->U+8005, U+FAB3->U+8352, U+FAB4->U+83EF, U+FAB5->U+8779, U+FAB6->U+8941, U+FAB7->U+8986, U+FAB8->U+8996, U+FAB9->U+8ABF, U+FABA->U+8AF8, U+FABB->U+8ACB,  \
U+FABC->U+8B01, U+FABD->U+8AFE, U+FABE->U+8AED, U+FABF->U+8B39, U+FAC0->U+8B8A, U+FAC1->U+8D08, U+FAC2->U+8F38, U+FAC3->U+9072, U+FAC4->U+9199, U+FAC5->U+9276, U+FAC6->U+967C, U+FAC7->U+96E3, U+FAC8->U+9756, U+FAC9->U+97DB, U+FACA->U+97FF, U+FACB->U+980B,  \
U+FACC->U+983B, U+FACD->U+9B12, U+FACE->U+9F9C, U+FACF->U+2284A, U+FAD0->U+22844, U+FAD1->U+233D5, U+FAD2->U+3B9D, U+FAD3->U+4018, U+FAD4->U+4039, U+FAD5->U+25249, U+FAD6->U+25CD0, U+FAD7->U+27ED3, U+FAD8->U+9F43, U+FAD9->U+9F8E, U+2F800->U+4E3D, U+2F801->U+4E38,  \
U+2F802->U+4E41, U+2F803->U+20122, U+2F804->U+4F60, U+2F805->U+4FAE, U+2F806->U+4FBB, U+2F807->U+5002, U+2F808->U+507A, U+2F809->U+5099, U+2F80A->U+50E7, U+2F80B->U+50CF, U+2F80C->U+349E, U+2F80D->U+2063A, U+2F80E->U+514D, U+2F80F->U+5154, U+2F810->U+5164,  \
U+2F811->U+5177, U+2F812->U+2051C, U+2F813->U+34B9, U+2F814->U+5167, U+2F815->U+518D, U+2F816->U+2054B, U+2F817->U+5197, U+2F818->U+51A4, U+2F819->U+4ECC, U+2F81A->U+51AC, U+2F81B->U+51B5, U+2F81C->U+291DF, U+2F81D->U+51F5, U+2F81E->U+5203, U+2F81F->U+34DF,  \
U+2F820->U+523B, U+2F821->U+5246, U+2F822->U+5272, U+2F823->U+5277, U+2F824->U+3515, U+2F825->U+52C7, U+2F826->U+52C9, U+2F827->U+52E4, U+2F828->U+52FA, U+2F829->U+5305, U+2F82A->U+5306, U+2F82B->U+5317, U+2F82C->U+5349, U+2F82D->U+5351, U+2F82E->U+535A,  \
U+2F82F->U+5373, U+2F830->U+537D, U+2F831->U+537F, U+2F832->U+537F, U+2F833->U+537F, U+2F834->U+20A2C, U+2F835->U+7070, U+2F836->U+53CA, U+2F837->U+53DF, U+2F838->U+20B63, U+2F839->U+53EB, U+2F83A->U+53F1, U+2F83B->U+5406, U+2F83C->U+549E, U+2F83D->U+5438,  \
U+2F83E->U+5448, U+2F83F->U+5468, U+2F840->U+54A2, U+2F841->U+54F6, U+2F842->U+5510, U+2F843->U+5553, U+2F844->U+5563, U+2F845->U+5584, U+2F846->U+5584, U+2F847->U+5599, U+2F848->U+55AB, U+2F849->U+55B3, U+2F84A->U+55C2, U+2F84B->U+5716, U+2F84C->U+5606,  \
U+2F84D->U+5717, U+2F84E->U+5651, U+2F84F->U+5674, U+2F850->U+5207, U+2F851->U+58EE, U+2F852->U+57CE, U+2F853->U+57F4, U+2F854->U+580D, U+2F855->U+578B, U+2F856->U+5832, U+2F857->U+5831, U+2F858->U+58AC, U+2F859->U+214E4, U+2F85A->U+58F2, U+2F85B->U+58F7,  \
U+2F85C->U+5906, U+2F85D->U+591A, U+2F85E->U+5922, U+2F85F->U+5962, U+2F860->U+216A8, U+2F861->U+216EA, U+2F862->U+59EC, U+2F863->U+5A1B, U+2F864->U+5A27, U+2F865->U+59D8, U+2F866->U+5A66, U+2F867->U+36EE, U+2F868->U+36FC, U+2F869->U+5B08, U+2F86A->U+5B3E,  \
U+2F86B->U+5B3E, U+2F86C->U+219C8, U+2F86D->U+5BC3, U+2F86E->U+5BD8, U+2F86F->U+5BE7, U+2F870->U+5BF3, U+2F871->U+21B18, U+2F872->U+5BFF, U+2F873->U+5C06, U+2F874->U+5F53, U+2F875->U+5C22, U+2F876->U+3781, U+2F877->U+5C60, U+2F878->U+5C6E, U+2F879->U+5CC0,  \
U+2F87A->U+5C8D, U+2F87B->U+21DE4, U+2F87C->U+5D43, U+2F87D->U+21DE6, U+2F87E->U+5D6E, U+2F87F->U+5D6B, U+2F880->U+5D7C, U+2F881->U+5DE1, U+2F882->U+5DE2, U+2F883->U+382F, U+2F884->U+5DFD, U+2F885->U+5E28, U+2F886->U+5E3D, U+2F887->U+5E69, U+2F888->U+3862,  \
U+2F889->U+22183, U+2F88A->U+387C, U+2F88B->U+5EB0, U+2F88C->U+5EB3, U+2F88D->U+5EB6, U+2F88E->U+5ECA, U+2F88F->U+2A392, U+2F890->U+5EFE, U+2F891->U+22331, U+2F892->U+22331, U+2F893->U+8201, U+2F894->U+5F22, U+2F895->U+5F22, U+2F896->U+38C7, U+2F897->U+232B8,  \
U+2F898->U+261DA, U+2F899->U+5F62, U+2F89A->U+5F6B, U+2F89B->U+38E3, U+2F89C->U+5F9A, U+2F89D->U+5FCD, U+2F89E->U+5FD7, U+2F89F->U+5FF9, U+2F8A0->U+6081, U+2F8A1->U+393A, U+2F8A2->U+391C, U+2F8A3->U+6094, U+2F8A4->U+226D4, U+2F8A5->U+60C7, U+2F8A6->U+6148,  \
U+2F8A7->U+614C, U+2F8A8->U+614E, U+2F8A9->U+614C, U+2F8AA->U+617A, U+2F8AB->U+618E, U+2F8AC->U+61B2, U+2F8AD->U+61A4, U+2F8AE->U+61AF, U+2F8AF->U+61DE, U+2F8B0->U+61F2, U+2F8B1->U+61F6, U+2F8B2->U+6210, U+2F8B3->U+621B, U+2F8B4->U+625D, U+2F8B5->U+62B1,  \
U+2F8B6->U+62D4, U+2F8B7->U+6350, U+2F8B8->U+22B0C, U+2F8B9->U+633D, U+2F8BA->U+62FC, U+2F8BB->U+6368, U+2F8BC->U+6383, U+2F8BD->U+63E4, U+2F8BE->U+22BF1, U+2F8BF->U+6422, U+2F8C0->U+63C5, U+2F8C1->U+63A9, U+2F8C2->U+3A2E, U+2F8C3->U+6469, U+2F8C4->U+647E,  \
U+2F8C5->U+649D, U+2F8C6->U+6477, U+2F8C7->U+3A6C, U+2F8C8->U+654F, U+2F8C9->U+656C, U+2F8CA->U+2300A, U+2F8CB->U+65E3, U+2F8CC->U+66F8, U+2F8CD->U+6649, U+2F8CE->U+3B19, U+2F8CF->U+6691, U+2F8D0->U+3B08, U+2F8D1->U+3AE4, U+2F8D2->U+5192, U+2F8D3->U+5195,  \
U+2F8D4->U+6700, U+2F8D5->U+669C, U+2F8D6->U+80AD, U+2F8D7->U+43D9, U+2F8D8->U+6717, U+2F8D9->U+671B, U+2F8DA->U+6721, U+2F8DB->U+675E, U+2F8DC->U+6753, U+2F8DD->U+233C3, U+2F8DE->U+3B49, U+2F8DF->U+67FA, U+2F8E0->U+6785, U+2F8E1->U+6852, U+2F8E2->U+6885,  \
U+2F8E3->U+2346D, U+2F8E4->U+688E, U+2F8E5->U+681F, U+2F8E6->U+6914, U+2F8E7->U+3B9D, U+2F8E8->U+6942, U+2F8E9->U+69A3, U+2F8EA->U+69EA, U+2F8EB->U+6AA8, U+2F8EC->U+236A3, U+2F8ED->U+6ADB, U+2F8EE->U+3C18, U+2F8EF->U+6B21, U+2F8F0->U+238A7, U+2F8F1->U+6B54,  \
U+2F8F2->U+3C4E, U+2F8F3->U+6B72, U+2F8F4->U+6B9F, U+2F8F5->U+6BBA, U+2F8F6->U+6BBB, U+2F8F7->U+23A8D, U+2F8F8->U+21D0B, U+2F8F9->U+23AFA, U+2F8FA->U+6C4E, U+2F8FB->U+23CBC, U+2F8FC->U+6CBF, U+2F8FD->U+6CCD, U+2F8FE->U+6C67, U+2F8FF->U+6D16, U+2F900->U+6D3E,  \
U+2F901->U+6D77, U+2F902->U+6D41, U+2F903->U+6D69, U+2F904->U+6D78, U+2F905->U+6D85, U+2F906->U+23D1E, U+2F907->U+6D34, U+2F908->U+6E2F, U+2F909->U+6E6E, U+2F90A->U+3D33, U+2F90B->U+6ECB, U+2F90C->U+6EC7, U+2F90D->U+23ED1, U+2F90E->U+6DF9, U+2F90F->U+6F6E,  \
U+2F910->U+23F5E, U+2F911->U+23F8E, U+2F912->U+6FC6, U+2F913->U+7039, U+2F914->U+701E, U+2F915->U+701B, U+2F916->U+3D96, U+2F917->U+704A, U+2F918->U+707D, U+2F919->U+7077, U+2F91A->U+70AD, U+2F91B->U+20525, U+2F91C->U+7145, U+2F91D->U+24263, U+2F91E->U+719C,  \
U+2F91F->U+243AB, U+2F920->U+7228, U+2F921->U+7235, U+2F922->U+7250, U+2F923->U+24608, U+2F924->U+7280, U+2F925->U+7295, U+2F926->U+24735, U+2F927->U+24814, U+2F928->U+737A, U+2F929->U+738B, U+2F92A->U+3EAC, U+2F92B->U+73A5, U+2F92C->U+3EB8, U+2F92D->U+3EB8,  \
U+2F92E->U+7447, U+2F92F->U+745C, U+2F930->U+7471, U+2F931->U+7485, U+2F932->U+74CA, U+2F933->U+3F1B, U+2F934->U+7524, U+2F935->U+24C36, U+2F936->U+753E, U+2F937->U+24C92, U+2F938->U+7570, U+2F939->U+2219F, U+2F93A->U+7610, U+2F93B->U+24FA1, U+2F93C->U+24FB8,  \
U+2F93D->U+25044, U+2F93E->U+3FFC, U+2F93F->U+4008, U+2F940->U+76F4, U+2F941->U+250F3, U+2F942->U+250F2, U+2F943->U+25119, U+2F944->U+25133, U+2F945->U+771E, U+2F946->U+771F, U+2F947->U+771F, U+2F948->U+774A, U+2F949->U+4039, U+2F94A->U+778B, U+2F94B->U+4046,  \
U+2F94C->U+4096, U+2F94D->U+2541D, U+2F94E->U+784E, U+2F94F->U+788C, U+2F950->U+78CC, U+2F951->U+40E3, U+2F952->U+25626, U+2F953->U+7956, U+2F954->U+2569A, U+2F955->U+256C5, U+2F956->U+798F, U+2F957->U+79EB, U+2F958->U+412F, U+2F959->U+7A40, U+2F95A->U+7A4A,  \
U+2F95B->U+7A4F, U+2F95C->U+2597C, U+2F95D->U+25AA7, U+2F95E->U+25AA7, U+2F95F->U+7AEE, U+2F960->U+4202, U+2F961->U+25BAB, U+2F962->U+7BC6, U+2F963->U+7BC9, U+2F964->U+4227, U+2F965->U+25C80, U+2F966->U+7CD2, U+2F967->U+42A0, U+2F968->U+7CE8, U+2F969->U+7CE3,  \
U+2F96A->U+7D00, U+2F96B->U+25F86, U+2F96C->U+7D63, U+2F96D->U+4301, U+2F96E->U+7DC7, U+2F96F->U+7E02, U+2F970->U+7E45, U+2F971->U+4334, U+2F972->U+26228, U+2F973->U+26247, U+2F974->U+4359, U+2F975->U+262D9, U+2F976->U+7F7A, U+2F977->U+2633E, U+2F978->U+7F95,  \
U+2F979->U+7FFA, U+2F97A->U+8005, U+2F97B->U+264DA, U+2F97C->U+26523, U+2F97D->U+8060, U+2F97E->U+265A8, U+2F97F->U+8070, U+2F980->U+2335F, U+2F981->U+43D5, U+2F982->U+80B2, U+2F983->U+8103, U+2F984->U+440B, U+2F985->U+813E, U+2F986->U+5AB5, U+2F987->U+267A7,  \
U+2F988->U+267B5, U+2F989->U+23393, U+2F98A->U+2339C, U+2F98B->U+8201, U+2F98C->U+8204, U+2F98D->U+8F9E, U+2F98E->U+446B, U+2F98F->U+8291, U+2F990->U+828B, U+2F991->U+829D, U+2F992->U+52B3, U+2F993->U+82B1, U+2F994->U+82B3, U+2F995->U+82BD, U+2F996->U+82E6,  \
U+2F997->U+26B3C, U+2F998->U+82E5, U+2F999->U+831D, U+2F99A->U+8363, U+2F99B->U+83AD, U+2F99C->U+8323, U+2F99D->U+83BD, U+2F99E->U+83E7, U+2F99F->U+8457, U+2F9A0->U+8353, U+2F9A1->U+83CA, U+2F9A2->U+83CC, U+2F9A3->U+83DC, U+2F9A4->U+26C36, U+2F9A5->U+26D6B,  \
U+2F9A6->U+26CD5, U+2F9A7->U+452B, U+2F9A8->U+84F1, U+2F9A9->U+84F3, U+2F9AA->U+8516, U+2F9AB->U+273CA, U+2F9AC->U+8564, U+2F9AD->U+26F2C, U+2F9AE->U+455D, U+2F9AF->U+4561, U+2F9B0->U+26FB1, U+2F9B1->U+270D2, U+2F9B2->U+456B, U+2F9B3->U+8650, U+2F9B4->U+865C,  \
U+2F9B5->U+8667, U+2F9B6->U+8669, U+2F9B7->U+86A9, U+2F9B8->U+8688, U+2F9B9->U+870E, U+2F9BA->U+86E2, U+2F9BB->U+8779, U+2F9BC->U+8728, U+2F9BD->U+876B, U+2F9BE->U+8786, U+2F9BF->U+45D7, U+2F9C0->U+87E1, U+2F9C1->U+8801, U+2F9C2->U+45F9, U+2F9C3->U+8860,  \
U+2F9C4->U+8863, U+2F9C5->U+27667, U+2F9C6->U+88D7, U+2F9C7->U+88DE, U+2F9C8->U+4635, U+2F9C9->U+88FA, U+2F9CA->U+34BB, U+2F9CB->U+278AE, U+2F9CC->U+27966, U+2F9CD->U+46BE, U+2F9CE->U+46C7, U+2F9CF->U+8AA0, U+2F9D0->U+8AED, U+2F9D1->U+8B8A, U+2F9D2->U+8C55,  \
U+2F9D3->U+27CA8, U+2F9D4->U+8CAB, U+2F9D5->U+8CC1, U+2F9D6->U+8D1B, U+2F9D7->U+8D77, U+2F9D8->U+27F2F, U+2F9D9->U+20804, U+2F9DA->U+8DCB, U+2F9DB->U+8DBC, U+2F9DC->U+8DF0, U+2F9DD->U+208DE, U+2F9DE->U+8ED4, U+2F9DF->U+8F38, U+2F9E0->U+285D2, U+2F9E1->U+285ED,  \
U+2F9E2->U+9094, U+2F9E3->U+90F1, U+2F9E4->U+9111, U+2F9E5->U+2872E, U+2F9E6->U+911B, U+2F9E7->U+9238, U+2F9E8->U+92D7, U+2F9E9->U+92D8, U+2F9EA->U+927C, U+2F9EB->U+93F9, U+2F9EC->U+9415, U+2F9ED->U+28BFA, U+2F9EE->U+958B, U+2F9EF->U+4995, U+2F9F0->U+95B7,  \
U+2F9F1->U+28D77, U+2F9F2->U+49E6, U+2F9F3->U+96C3, U+2F9F4->U+5DB2, U+2F9F5->U+9723, U+2F9F6->U+29145, U+2F9F7->U+2921A, U+2F9F8->U+4A6E, U+2F9F9->U+4A76, U+2F9FA->U+97E0, U+2F9FB->U+2940A, U+2F9FC->U+4AB2, U+2F9FD->U+29496, U+2F9FE->U+980B, U+2F9FF->U+980B,  \
U+2FA00->U+9829, U+2FA01->U+295B6, U+2FA02->U+98E2, U+2FA03->U+4B33, U+2FA04->U+9929, U+2FA05->U+99A7, U+2FA06->U+99C2, U+2FA07->U+99FE, U+2FA08->U+4BCE, U+2FA09->U+29B30, U+2FA0A->U+9B12, U+2FA0B->U+9C40, U+2FA0C->U+9CFD, U+2FA0D->U+4CCE, U+2FA0E->U+4CED,  \
U+2FA0F->U+9D67, U+2FA10->U+2A0CE, U+2FA11->U+4CF8, U+2FA12->U+2A105, U+2FA13->U+2A20E, U+2FA14->U+2A291, U+2FA15->U+9EBB, U+2FA16->U+4D56, U+2FA17->U+9EF9, U+2FA18->U+9EFE, U+2FA19->U+9F05, U+2FA1A->U+9F0F, U+2FA1B->U+9F16, U+2FA1C->U+9F3B, U+2FA1D->U+2A600,  \
U+2F00->U+4E00, U+2F01->U+4E28, U+2F02->U+4E36, U+2F03->U+4E3F, U+2F04->U+4E59, U+2F05->U+4E85, U+2F06->U+4E8C, U+2F07->U+4EA0, U+2F08->U+4EBA, U+2F09->U+51
```

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://yob.id.au/2008/05/08/thinking-sphinx-and-unicode.html) saved my day! But there are few things you should consider: charset_table must be placed in one line and there should be no quotes for charset_table. Only then it worked for me.